# Delete model-mommy instance

Tags: django, model-mommy

I'm using [model-mommy](https://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to generate test data like so

```
class AuthorDetailViewTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # set bio manually to avoid error being thrown by template tag markdown_format
        self.author = mommy.make('author.Author', bio='Some bio text')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.author.delete()
```

`setUp()` method works fine. Problem is that the `tearDown()` method doesn't actually delete the created a`author` instance. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks